# X-Download-Options: noopen equivalent

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, http-headers

The HTTP Header `X-Download-Options: noopen` alters Internet Explorer download dialog by removing the "open with" option. (The only remaining option becomes: "save as" and "cancel")

Do you know if there's a cross-browser equivalent to this header ?

Answer (score 2):

That's an IE extension and other browsers haven't adopted it.

The best you can do is `Content-Disposition:attachment`, but that doesn't hide the Open option.