# What does `X-Download-Options: noopen` do?

Tags: http, security, internet-explorer, https, http-headers

I'm looking at the defaults of Helmet.js and encountered with `X-Download-Options`
Currently, I've found these:

- It's only for IE8
- In IE8 if you don't give `noopen` to this header, any downloaded HTML file's js will run in the current site's context
- [Another question about `X-Download-Options`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15299325/x-download-options-noopen-equivalent) says it removes the open button and alters it with a save button

Is below a possible attack that must be prevented with `X-Download-Options`

Site foo.com allow one user to store file and another user to download the file

- Bad guy: Stores an HTML file which sends him user's cookies `localStorage` etc via js
- User: Downloads this file, it immediately opens and runs the js, everything is gone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One year later, I stumbled on same question but found an answer.

https://www.invicti.com/white-papers/whitepaper-http-security-headers/#XDownloadOptionsHTTPHeader

TLDR: Downloaded html file will be executed in site's context, so attacker can access cookie etc.